# There is a big offer of computers on the market?

Tags: grammar

I am thinking about how to express this idea. I want to say that the market is saturated by computers. So:

> - There is a big offer of computer on the market

or

> - There is a big computer offer on the market

Which one sounds better?

Thank you all

Comment: You can't say "offer of computer" because *computer* is countable, so must either be plural or have a determiner of some sort. However, questions on this site need to be scoped to **some point of grammar or usage.** What is the actual doubt that you have about your alternatives? **Why** are you asking about them? "Which one sounds better?" is simply inviting opinion.

Comment: You might be interested in our sister site called [ELL.SE]. Their criteria are a little less strict than ours, because the target community is different.

Comment: Neither one makes much sense.  There is a glut of computers on the market.  The computer market is saturated.  Too many computers are for sale.  And many others.

Comment: Neither makes sense as there must be multiple offers. 'There are many good deals for computers available.'

Comment: Or "Many computers are offered on the market".  But saying "There is a big offer" is not the fluent way to say it.

Comment: As a fluent Spanish speaker and English mother tongue speaker, I have given  you an answer and you have not even responded. Don't worry, when I started translating 35 years ago, I translated "inversión" as inversion instead of investment.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing **oferta** and **offer**. **Oferta in English** is **supply**, not offer here.

- The supply and demand for computers.
- La oferta y la demanda para las computadores [Latam Spanish] o los ordenadores [Iberian Spanish].

There is **a huge supply of computers** on the market.
OR
There is **a huge supply of computers** saturating the market.
OR
**The market is saturated with a huge supply of computers**.

huge, large, enormous, big, etc.

[This is a typical false friend and if you don't actively translate from Spanish, you might miss it...]

Answer (score -1):

Neither of your sentences sounds very English. The same words might sound good in other languages, but the mere translation word-for-word does not work in this case.

One way to convey the meaning is:

> There is an abundance of computers on the market.

or:

> There is a big variety of computers available for purchase.

and others as well.

---

@J.R. noted in a comment:

> These two suggestions both work, but their implications might differ slightly. *There is an abundance of computers on the market* suggests that inventories are high, almost to the point where consumers might see a price drop or some good sale prices. On the other hand, *There is a big variety of computers available for purchase* only suggests that several options are available, but suggests nothing about how many computers might be in stock in the warehouse or at the store.

Comment: How about "The market is saturated by computers"?

Comment: I’d say “The market is saturated with computers”. “By computers” would mean the computers put all kinds of things on the market and saturated it.  “With computers” means lots of companies have built too many computers and try to sell them.